# Laurent Series Coefficients Problem.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I am struggling with a question regarding Laurent's Theorem and the coefficients of a Laurent series.  The question is attached above.  I know the general formula for coefficients.  I have set $z=e^{i \theta}$. I have plugged in also $f(z)$ into the coefficient  formula given by Laurent's Theorem.  I however, cannot get the answer to be or look like the integral for the coefficients with the cosine etc, given in the question, which is what we are trying to prove or show.  Do you have any pointers or suggestions?  That would really help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $e^{z+\frac{1}{z}}$ is holomorphic everywhere in $0 < |z| < \infty$ and, therefore, has a Laurent series expansions
$$
            e^{z+\frac{1}{z}} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n z^n, \;\;\; 0 < |z| < \infty.
$$
The Laurent series coefficients $a_n$ are given by
\begin{align}
      a_n&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}e^{z+\frac{1}{z}}\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}dz \\
    &= \frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}e^{-i(n+1)\theta}e^{i\theta}d\theta \\
    &= \frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{2\cos\theta}e^{-in\theta}d\theta \\
    &= \frac{1}{2\pi }\left(\int_{-\pi}^{0}+\int_{0}^{\pi}\right)e^{2\cos\theta}e^{-in\theta}d\theta \\
    &= \frac{1}{2\pi }\left( 
   - \int_{\pi}^{0}e^{2\cos(-\theta)}e^{in\theta}d\theta+\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{2\cos\theta}e^{-in\theta}d\theta\right) \\
    &= \frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{2\cos\theta}(e^{in\theta}+e^{-in\theta})d\theta \\
    &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{2\cos\theta}\cos(n\theta)d\theta.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you.  I just don't understand the part, where you break up into two integrals, could you please explain.  Also why do you integrate from pi to -pi.  Can you also integrate from 0 to 2pi?

Comment: How would I do this integrating from 0 to 2pi, is my question.

Comment: @BOB : You can do with $[0,\pi]$, $[\pi,2\pi]$, but the simplification will take more steps because you'll still want to get the second part over $[0,\pi]$ in order to combine integrals. Breaking into $[-\pi,0]$, $[0,\pi]$ is the same because the integrand is $2\pi$ periodic in $\theta$.

Comment: I see that makes, thanks so much.  One last question.  I don't really understand the step from the 2nd to the last step.  How do you get cos(theta) and how exactly did you bring out the 2.  I don't exactly see it.

Comment: @BOB: Let $\theta = -\alpha$: Then $\int_{-\pi}^{0}f(\theta)d\theta = -\int_{\pi}^{0}f(-\alpha)d\alpha = -\int_{\pi}^{0}f(-\theta)d\theta$.

Comment: I mean the step where you get cos(ntheta0.  How does e^(i*n*theta) +e^(-i*n*theta) equal to cos(ntheta)?

Comment: @BOB : $e^{in\theta}+e^{-in\theta}=2\cos(n\theta)$. Then notice that the $2$ cancelled the $2$ in $\frac{1}{2\pi}$.

Comment: Yes exactly. But could you show that e^(intheta) +e^(-intheta) =2cos(theta).  I just don't follow.  could you please explain that step?  Much appreciated.

Comment: @BOB : $e^{i\alpha}=\cos(\alpha)+i\sin(\alpha)$. $e^{-i\alpha}=\cos(\alpha)-i\sin(\alpha)$. Now add the two and divide by $2$.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense, just trying to understand everything!

Comment: @BOB : Glad to help.